# Forward declaration issue, two compilers

Tags: c, linux

I've been developing in C using eclipse as my IDE in my virtual machine with ubuntu, I've made some progress and I wanted to test them in the real product which is an embedded system using powerpc.

In order to compile that program for our product I use Code::Blocks in Windows but the compiler is a powerpc version of the gcc.

The same code is giving me an error in the powerpc version that doesn't appear in the ubuntu version.

I have two header files **gral.h** and **module_hand.h** as follows:

The **gral.h** file:

```
#ifndef HEADERS_GRAL_H_
#define HEADERS_GRAL_H_

#include "module_hand.h"

typedef struct PROFILE
{
    module_t  mod;    // this one comes from module_hand.h
    int       var1;   // some other random variables
} profile_t;

#endif /* HEADERS_GRAL_H_ */
```

The **module_hand.h** is defined as follows

```
#ifndef HEADERS_MODULE_HAND_H_
#define HEADERS_MODULE_HAND_H_

#include <stdint.h>

#include "gral.h"

typedef struct PROFILE profile_t;

typedef struct module
{
    char  name[30];       // name of module
    char  rev[30];        // module revision
    char  mfr[30];        // manufacturer
} module_t;

int Mod_Init(profile_t *profile);
/*  some other random functions */

#endif /* HEADERS_MODULE_HAND_H_*/
```

As you'll see, I don't use the `PROFILE struct` in the `module struct`, But I declare it forward to use it in the declaration of the `Mod_Init` function

This gives me a `Error: redefinition of typedef 'profile_t'`
and `error: previous declaration of 'profile_t' was here`

If I remove the forward declaration the error is `Error: parse error before '*' token`
where the line number is the line of the function declaration.

My doubt is what am I missing, and why gcc in Ubuntu does compile it with no problem.

Comment: Which of these headers do you include in your C file? If both, in which order do you include them?

Comment: Well I have two c files I only include the Gral.h file in my main.c, however in my module_hand.c file both files are included, the Gral.h file being the first one

Comment: The Ubuntu version of gcc compiles with no problems because the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Note that your two headers mutually include each other.  That's always a terrible idea.  Figure out which order you want them compiled in and fix the mutual inclusion.

Comment: Do you get the same errors for both C files?

Comment: What versions of GCC are you using? What compilation options?  In particular, are you using a `-std=` option for either build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I read your answers and comments and decided to try another approach.

As some of you said, I had some kind of recursion, I wanted to keep every structure within its respective header file, but now, I dropped the idea and merged the structures in one file only.

My new approach:

Gral.h

```
#ifndef HEADERS_GRAL_H_
#define HEADERS_GRAL_H_

typedef struct module
{
    char  name[30];       // name of module
    char  rev[30];        // module revision
    char  mfr[30];        // manufacturer
} module_t;

typedef struct PROFILE {
    module_t  mod;    // this one comes from module_hand.h
    int       var1;   // some other variables
} profile_t;

#endif /* HEADERS_GRAL_H_ */:
```

Module.h

```
#ifndef HEADERS_MODULE_HAND_H_
#define HEADERS_MODULE_HAND_H_

#include <Gral.h>

int Mod_Init(profile_t *profile);
/* some other functions */

#endif /* HEADERS_MODULE_HAND_H_*/
```

And when any other structure comes up, I'll declare it in Gral.h and include the header file.

Regarding the compilers, they aren't the same version. The powerpc is quite old now. That would explain the powerpc compilation errors.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Your powerpc compiler is enforcing the C99 rule that

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one
> declaration of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) with
> the same scope and in the same name space, except for tags as
> specified in 6.7.2.3.

(C99 6.7/3)

Your Linux compiler is observing the relaxed version of that rule that was introduced in C11:

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one
> declaration of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) with
> the same scope and in the same name space, except that:
>
> - a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does, provided that type is not a variably modified type;
> - tags may be redeclared as specified in 6.7.2.3.

(C11 6.7/3; also C17 6.7/3)

Supposing that the compilation options are the same, the behavior difference surely arises from using different versions of GCC.  More recent versions default to more recent versions of the language.

You could try adding `-std=gnu11` or `-std=c11` to the command-line options (for both targets) to try to get consistency.  If your powerpc version of GCC is too old to accept those then you really need to update to a newer version.

**Note also**, however, that you don't need to have this problem in the first place.  Given that `module_hand.h` includes `gral.h`, the former has no need whatever to redefine a typedef that the latter already defines.

Moreover, the fact that these two headers each include the other is a strong suggestion that they ought to be combined into one.  Multiple-inclusion guards prevent an actual loop, but they are not an adequate solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the **gral.h** header file, you define `profile_t` using `typedef`, then you redefine `profile_t` with another `typedef` in **module_hand.h**.  You should just define the `struct PROFILE` in **gral_h** and include **gral.h** in **module_hand.h**.

**gral.h**:

```
#ifndef HEADERS_GRAL_H_
#define HEADERS_GRAL_H_

#include "module_hand.h"

typedef struct PROFILE {
    module_t  mod;    // this one comes from module_hand.h
    int       var1;   // some other random variables
} profile_t;

#endif /* HEADERS_GRAL_H_ */:
```

**module_hand.h**:

```
#ifndef HEADERS_MODULE_HAND_H_
#define HEADERS_MODULE_HAND_H_

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct module
{
    char  name[30];       // name of module
    char  rev[30];        // module revision
    char  mfr[30];        // manufacturer
} module_t;

int Mod_Init(struct PROFILE *profile);
/* some other random functions */

#endif /* HEADERS_MODULE_HAND_H_*/
```